# Embed SWF with header and footer

Tags: css, html

I am having trouble making my website have a header, an embedded swf in the middle and then a footer. Every time it ends up making my page have to do a vertical scroll by the size of the header+footer. I am using swfObject and embedding the swf at 100% width and 100% height.

Does anyone know how to setup the correct ordering of div's and css to make the swf scale to the empty space in between the header and footer?

I am trying to use the following format

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="content"> SWF would go here
    <div id="footer">
</div> end container
```

Comment: Is your SWF set up to be scalable first?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: I do my own scaling in the SWF based on the stage width and stage height.

Comment: position: absolute; top: FOOpx; bottom: BARpx; swfobject is bogus, try http://reisio.com/examples/flash/

Comment: make a demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking...? :O

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header"> <p align="center"> Header</p>  </div>

<div id="content"> 
        <object width="400" height="80%"
            classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
            <param name="SRC" value="bookmark.swf">
            <embed src="bookmark.swf" width="100%" height="80%"></embed>
        </object>
</div>

<div id="footer"> <p align="center"> Footer</p>  </div>
```

---

### or

You can use `javascript` method.
First findout the spacing between header and footer, and then resize the flash. The following script may help you.

```
  <script>
  function myFunction()
    {
      // get the heights //
      var containerHeight = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight;
      var headerHeight = document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
      var footerHeight = document.getElementById("footer").offsetHeight;

      // get the vertical spacing //      
      var height_of_flash = containerHeight-(headerHeight+footerHeight);

      // set the heights //
      var e1 = document.getElementById("object_swf");
      e1.style.height =  height_of_flash;
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: No. The swf needs to take up all of the empty space in between the header and footer, not a static 40 pixels.

Comment: This would only work if the header and footer take up 20%. That isn't really the desired effect. The header and footer should never scale (they have designated pixel amounts) and the SWF should scale to take up all of the remaining space for any browser size. With the right nesting of div's and CSS settings I think you should be able to have the height of the SWF at 100% and it would fill the empty space. I just can't figure out how to do that.